# Show all the data from the given date through php condition

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table

I am generating a data from the database to html table using php.
I want to output with php condition using the student joining date.

I want to run a condition where you take the `j.date` and anything before should have `-` and after should have a 'Pay' button which holds the `studentid`

```
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
| Student |   J.date   | Jan | Feb | Mar  | Apr  | May  | ... |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
| John    | 25-03-2018 |   0 |   0 | 2000 |    0 | 1750 | ... |
| Michael | 10-04-2018 |   0 |   0 |    0 | 5000 |    0 | ... |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
```

Something like this

```
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
| Student |   J.date   | Jan | Feb | Mar  | Apr  | May  | ... |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
| John    | 25-03-2018 |   - |   - | 2000 | Pay  | 1750 | ... |
| Michael | 10-04-2018 |   - |   - |    - | 5000 | Pay  | ... |
+---------+------------+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----+
```

#### Updated

The query

```
<?php
$sqlFees = "SELECT
            s.student_id, s.firstname, s.lastname,
            c.subject, c.standard, (t.month * c.fee) AS coursefee,
            SUM(f.paid) AS paid, MIN(f.paiddate) AS studentstartdate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 1 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MJan,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 2 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MFeb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 3 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MMar,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 4 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MApr,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 5 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MMay,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 6 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MJun,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 7 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MJul,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 8 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MAug,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 9 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MSep,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 10 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MOct,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 11 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MNov,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(f.paiddate) = 12 THEN f.paid ELSE 0 END) AS MDec
        FROM
            fees f
                JOIN enrollments e ON f.enrollmentid = e.enrollment_id
                LEFT JOIN courses c ON e.courseid = c.course_id
                LEFT JOIN students s ON f.studentid = s.student_id
                LEFT JOIN terms t ON e.termid = t.term_id
        WHERE
            f.paiddate BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY
            f.enrollmentid
        ORDER BY NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT studentid
                    FROM fees f
                WHERE f.enrollmentid = e.enrollment_id
                AND MONTH(f.paiddate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
                ) DESC
                ";
$resultFees = mysqli_query($con, $sqlFees);
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="8" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sep</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Paid so far</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
    </thead>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultFees)) :
    $studentId = $row['student_id'];
    $studentFName = $row['firstname'];
    $studentLName = $row['lastname'];
    $studentFullName = $studentFName.' '.$studentLName;
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $standard = $row['standard'];
    $paid = $row['paid'];
    $courseFee = $row['coursefee'];
    $studentStartDate = $row['studentstartdate']; // this is the J.date
    $monthJan = $row['MJan'];
    $monthFeb = $row['MFeb'];
    $monthMar = $row['MMar'];
    $monthApr = $row['MApr'];
    $monthMay = $row['MMay'];
    $monthJun = $row['MJun'];
    $monthJul = $row['MJul'];
    $monthAug = $row['MAug'];
    $monthSep = $row['MSep'];
    $monthOct = $row['MOct'];
    $monthNov = $row['MNov'];
    $monthMDec = $row['MDec'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $studentId.' '.$studentFullName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $subject.' '.$standard.'<br>'.$courseFee; ?></td>
        <td id="0"><?php echo $monthJan; ?></td>
        <td id="1"><?php echo $monthFeb; ?></td>
        <td id="2"><?php echo $monthMar; ?></td>
        <td id="3"><?php echo $monthApr; ?></td>
        <td id="4"><?php echo $monthMay; ?></td>
        <td id="5"><?php echo $monthJun; ?></td>
        <td id="6"><?php echo $monthJul; ?></td>
        <td id="7"><?php echo $monthAug; ?></td>
        <td id="8"><?php echo $monthSep; ?></td>
        <td id="9"><?php echo $monthOct; ?></td>
        <td id="10"><?php echo $monthNov; ?></td>
        <td id="11"><?php echo $monthMDec; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $paid.'/- '; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $studentStartDate; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far ? SO is not here to do your homework for you, we help you with specific problems with code, to help you learn, but we can only do that if we understand where you are going wrong.

Comment: `$monthJan = ($row['jdate'] > 0) ? '-' : $monthJan;`. I know this is wrong. but i am not sure.

Comment: @DarkMukke the `J.date` is the  `studentstartdate`

Comment: Can you add the php code to the question too please ?

Comment: @DarkMukke Updated the code. Please excuse for the shabby code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatPay($value, $date, $date2) {
  if($value == 0) {
    if(strtotime($date) < strtotime($date2) {
      $output = '-';
    } else {
      $output = 'Pay';
    }
  } else {
    $output = $value;
  }
  return $output;
}
$studentStartDate = $row['studentstartdate']; // this is the J.date
$monthJan = formatPay($row['MJan'],$studentStartDate,'01-01-2018');
$monthFeb = formatPay($row['MFeb'],$studentStartDate,'01-02-2018');
$monthMar = formatPay($row['MMar'],$studentStartDate,'01-03-2018');
$monthApr = formatPay($row['MApr'],$studentStartDate,'01-04-2018');
$monthMay = formatPay($row['MMay'],$studentStartDate,'01-05-2018');
$monthJun = formatPay($row['MJun'],$studentStartDate,'01-06-2018');
$monthJul = formatPay($row['MJul'],$studentStartDate,'01-07-2018');
$monthAug = formatPay($row['MAug'],$studentStartDate,'01-08-2018');
$monthSep = formatPay($row['MSep'],$studentStartDate,'01-09-2018');
$monthOct = formatPay($row['MOct'],$studentStartDate,'01-10-2018');
$monthNov = formatPay($row['MNov'],$studentStartDate,'01-11-2018');
$monthMDec = formatPay($row['MDec'],$studentStartDate,'01-12-2018');
```

Unless I made a typo somewhere, this should work. Since your code is kind of messy, it's easiest to just make a function that handles this conversion.

Comment: that why we comment and wait for a more complete question before answering

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment. For some reason you need 50 rep, and I can't earn rep unless I answer

Comment: I updated my original answer to fit with your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is something like this. You could do this in the SQL but since you asked for a php solution, here it is.

I stripped out the query and reformatted some of the html to gain some vertical space.
I also used a button template that you can adjust which ever way you want. I used an array for the months and loop through it and then loop again in the html table cols. The array is not necessary but I prefer to do my calculations outside of my view/template. Also this makes it easier to understand/read.

```
<?php
$sqlFees = <<<SQL
...
SQL;
$resultFees = mysqli_query($con, $sqlFees);
$buttonTemplate = '<button data-studentid="%s">Pay</button>';
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="8" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>Subject</th>
    <th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th>
    <th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th>
    <th>Paid so far</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultFees)) :
        $button = sprintf($buttonTemplate, $row['student_id']);
        $joinDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['studentstartdate']);
        $joinMonth = $joinDate->format('m');
        $courseFee = $row['coursefee'];
        $payments = [ $row['MJan'], $row['MFeb'], $row['MMar'], $row['MApr'], $row['MMay'],
            $row['MJun'], $row['MJul'], $row['MAug'], $row['MSep'], $row['MOct'], $row['MNov'], $row['MDec']];
        $buttons = [];
        foreach ($payments as $month => $paid) {
            if($joinMonth > ($month + 1)) {
                $buttons[$month] = '-';
                continue;
            }
            if(0 === (int)$paid) {
                $buttons[$month] = $button;
                continue;
            }
            $buttons[$month] = $paid;
        }


        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['subject'] . ' ' . $row['standard'] . '<br>' . $row['paid']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach($buttons as $mon => $but): ?>
            <td id="<?= $mon; ?>"><?= $but; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <td><?= $row['paid']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['studentstartdate']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The important bit is :

```
    foreach ($payments as $month => $paid) {
        if($joinMonth > ($month + 1)) {
            $buttons[$month] = '-';
            continue;
        }
        if(0 === (int)$paid) {
            $buttons[$month] = $button;
            continue;
        }
        $buttons[$month] = $paid;
    }
```

In the first if, it checks if the student was actually joined, (and since i used an array index, i need to add one to the month).
In the second if, it checks to see if there was no payment made and adds the button.
And by default it shows the value paid.

One thing to note is that you could do this in an if-elseif-else structure, but i'd like to show some different way of addressing this, and this way is also slightly faster (micro optimizations)

Answer (score -1):

your question is unclear but i'll give a try.

You could do something like this :

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $j.date);
```

then in your table :

```
<?= $date->format('m') < $yourMonth ? '-' : $date->format('m') == $yourMonth ? $yourNumber : $date->format('m') +1 == $yourMonth ? 'Pay' : $yourNumber ?>
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Questions should be clear but answers should be even clearer.